# Noticeable projects in build tools ( ant , maven and gradle )?

Tags: maven, ant, build-automation, gradle

I'm comparing ant, maven and gradle to suggest one tool to my project. I have found projects like hiberante, grails, groovy and spring uses gradle. But could not found any noticeable projects in ant and maven. Does anybody knows such projects ? 
Also i would like read your comments on these build tools so I can choose the best one.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One prominent Open source project that uses Ant is [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/). You can find their build script [here](https://github.com/apache/tomcat70/blob/trunk/build.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Apache Wicket and Apache Camel come to mind as popular projects that use Maven.

As for Ant, I don't really know. Spring used to, but as you said it now uses Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://builds.apache.org there you will find many examples for all tools